# Sorting by the elements that come first in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to get an answer `['H','H','A',A]`
from the input `['H','A','H','A']`

How to sort it based from the char that comes up first?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Search your favourite search engine for `sort arrays in javascript`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan, the question, as i read it, is to sort by the occurence and group same values, but not like sorting by alphabet or by words. maybe the OP can add some try and the question could be reopened.

Comment: Ah, I see - there is not enough information to gather how to sort an array with more than 2 letters so far

Comment: AFAIK, this seems like a quite unique way of sorting an array, and if someone of Nina's caliber answered and didn't mark it as duplicate, I vote it as a useful question and can't think of a fit close reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) by using a temporary object with a hashtable for the same group counter.

The sorting happens with the group.

The result is mapped with index of the sorted temporary array.

```js
var array = ['H', 'A', 'H', 'A'],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    counter = 0,
    result = array
        .map((v, index) => ({ index, group: groups[v] = groups[v] || ++counter }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group)
        .map(o => array[o.index]);

console.log(result);
```

The same, but with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the order of the first occurence.

```js
var array = ['H', 'A', 'H', 'A'],
    map = new Map;

array.forEach(v => map.has(v) || map.set(v, map.size + 1));

array.sort((a, b) => map.get(a) - map.get(b));

console.log(array);
```